# Disable text below barcode image in Code39Bean

Tags: java

This code creates BarCode Image along with Text below image  . 
I need to remove the text from image . 
Code39Bean does not have any property to disable this .

```
public static ByteArrayOutputStream generateBarcodeImg(String inputId)
            throws Exception {

        ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

        Code39Bean bean = new Code39Bean();
        final int dpi = 150;

        /**
         * Configure the bar-code generator and makes the narrow bar width
         * exactly one pixel.
         */
        bean.setModuleWidth(UnitConv.in2mm(1.0f / dpi));
        bean.setWideFactor(3);
        bean.doQuietZone(false);

        try {

            /** Set up the canvas provider for monochrome PNG output. */
            BitmapCanvasProvider canvas = new BitmapCanvasProvider(baos,
                    BarCodeConstant.CONTENT_TYPE, dpi,
                    BufferedImage.TYPE_BYTE_BINARY, false, 0);

            /** Generate the bar code. */
            bean.generateBarcode(canvas, inputId);

            /** Signal end of generation. */
            canvas.finish();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            logger.error(
                    "Exception occured in BarcodeGeneration: generateBarcodeImg "
                            + e.getLocalizedMessage(), e);
            throw new MobileResourceException(
                    "Exception occured in BarcodeGeneration: generateBarcodeImg",
                    null);
        }
        return baos;

    }
}
```

Answer (score 9):

You can remove the text from Image through the "HumanReadablePlacement" property:

```
bean.setMsgPosition(HumanReadablePlacement.HRP_NONE);
```

This will suppress the human readable text of the barcode to NONE.